# Django-oembed Flash media z-index is not working.

Tags: django, oembed, video-embedding, django-oembed

Background:-

I am using Django-oembed for embedding youtube videos.

```
{% oembed 250x140 %}
            {{ shastra.content_id.video_content_id.url|safe }}
        {% endoembed %}
```

Problem:-
The problem I am facing On "Google Chrome" is that the embedded video is overlapping my header and footer. How can I fix it using django-oembed? If not is there a alternative that I can use ?

[image: Overlap]

Answer (score 1):

Does the rendered HTML have anything you can grab onto and restyle with CSS? Whenever I encounter something like this, I usually just override the application's CSS with my own. Many times, the styling included with the app is more of a guideline than something that's been fully tested.

Comment: Hi @kcunning no there is no css associated with it. Am unable to override it.

Comment: Hmm. Do you have an example that's live? That might make it a bit easier for me to help out with.

Comment: Hey the above is a live example. Django-oembed(Its a django package ) is used in the above manner in the templates. 
And the video is coming over the bar as shown in the image.

Comment: No, I mean an example on a website that I can go to. I understand what you're saying, but I'm not going to set up django-oembed on a test server so I can help debug it.

Comment: Sorry its not on live server .

Comment: Hi I finally was able to solve the issue. By using jquery to over ride the wmode. By adding wmode=transparent in the src of the Iframe that was being rendered by the oembed tag.